# Selecting some data of a single column from one table and insert into another table in MySql

Tags: mysql

My Query:

```
  INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) 
    SELECT DISTINCT c4
          FROM `imp_asset` WHERE c4 !='' ORDER BY c4 ASC;

Error Code: 1062
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

My Test table:

```
Field   Type
id      int(11) NOT NULL
name    varchar(200) NULL
```

Comment: Make the `id` field auto_increment. `ALTER TABLE test CHANGE id id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your table as:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test(
  id      int(11) NOT NULL,
  name    varchar(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

or if the table is already created then try to alter it using the ALTER statement.

```
alter table test modify column id INT auto_increment;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ID is of type INT and is a primary key, but on your insert query you are not specifying any value for ID and there's no default value defined.

You have to make your ID column as an auto_increment:

```
alter table test modify column id int auto_increment;
```

Please see an [example fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b058f/1).